# Compare columns and dedupe

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, duplicates, serverless

Please see below a table where I would like to create a distinct list of telephone numbers, the ranking GROUP numbers need to take priority descending 1-4. The example should result in ID 4, 9,10 (highlighted as red x) being removed as they share duplicate telephone numbers but in a lower priority GROUP.

I have managed to do this a long way round in many steps and creating a surrogate key, but I would like it if someone could show me how this could be done in a single step, for efficiency (and to sharpen up my SQL).

In SAS9 I had a **coalescec** function where I was able to create a new variable and instruct the priority - but I know of no such function in SQL.

https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.1/ds2ref/n0crpo0xd76wb3n1poba9wmu1a6q.htm

[image: Markers showing the duplicates - green stay - red remove]

please see mock data in SQL below

```
    CREATE TABLE MT_TEMP_TEL2 (
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  GROUP INT NOT NULL,
  TEL1 VARCHAR(11),
  TEL2 VARCHAR(11),
  TEL3 VARCHAR(11),
  TEL4 VARCHAR(11)
);

INSERT INTO MT_TEMP_TEL2
VALUES 
  (1,4,"79000000000","","",""),
  (2,1,"12111111111","79999999999","",""),
  (3,1,"","13842222222","",""),
  (4,2,"","","78888888888","12111111111"),
  (5,3,"","73333333333","",""),
  (6,1,"15278888888","","",""),
  (7,2,"","","71111111111",""),
  (8,4,"","13843333333","","72222222222"),
  (9,4,"","73333333333","",""),
  (10,3,"75555555555","","12155555555","13842222222");
```

Here is the desired results as stated above, we have now removed rows 4, 9 and 10

| ID | GROUP | TEL1 | TEL2 | TEL3 | TEL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 79000000000 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 1 | 12111111111 | 79999999999 |  |  |
| 3 | 1 |  | 13842222222 |  |  |
| 5 | 3 |  | 73333333333 |  |  |
| 6 | 1 | 15278888888 |  |  |  |
| 7 | 2 |  |  | 71111111111 |  |
| 8 | 4 |  | 13843333333 |  | 72222222222 |

Comment: Please provide what you already tried. Also most SQL dialects have a `coalesce` function (or a similar function with a different name) which does exactly what SAS `coalescec` does only for character types.

Comment: please tag your database system

Comment: Please include sample data as text ideally with `create table` and `insert` statements [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sure - i'll mock one up now

Comment: I've updated with the data

Comment: Can you also include your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had assumed with the mention of `coalesce` that the goal was to have the 4 columns condensed into a single list of values, the expected results example shows now that's not the case.

There are a few ways to tackle this, one is to use `window functions` to assign a sequential number to each reccuring value; to do that, the values must be combined into a single list for which you can use `union`, the results of which are then `partitioned` by the combined values and each *duplicate* gets a sequential row number. It's then a matter of keeping just those with a value of 1.

```
with Alltel as (
    select id, [group], tel1 from MT_TEMP_TEL2 union all
    select id, [group], tel2 from MT_TEMP_TEL2 union all
    select id, [group], tel3 from MT_TEMP_TEL2 union all
    select id, [group], tel4 from MT_TEMP_TEL2 
), rn as (
    select id, tel1, Row_Number() over (partition by tel1 order by [group]) n
    from alltel
    where tel1 !=''
)
select * 
from MT_TEMP_TEL2 t
where not exists (select * from rn where rn.id=t.id and rn.n>1)
```

Comment: I'm just taking a look right now - i really appreciate your explination and the theory behind your code. i seem to still be getting 10 rows, is it AlllTel i need to view or MT_TEMP_TEL2?

Comment: @teelove I have created [a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f251cae94872cb1e291c75be8f7b69e) showing it working for you.

Comment: PERFECT - i think my tel fields were NULL not " " in the database - thank you so much, i will look more into your explination as i fear this is not the last time this problem will occur.

Comment: @teelove I did wonder but used your sample data which had strings throughout - easy enough to accomodate though.

Comment: Hi Stu - i'm mega happy to leave this as solved, i've just discoverd an issue witth real data which i didnt anticipate - in some telephone fields they can have the the same number in tel1 and tel3 for example, for example - in row6, if we add the same unique number into tel3, the code will omit that row, as its a duplicate to that row, not the table, ideally i need a way to keep that row - any ideas?

Comment: just to give you some contect tel1 could be "DAYTIME" phone number for the callcentre and tel2 could be "EVENING" so even though they are duppes, the dialler would only pick up tthe fields it needs

Comment: @teelove Yes probably in this case you need to remove duplicates, try just `union` instead of `union all`